# Finding string inside quotes and and loading it to a textbox

Tags: c#

just a couple of questions

I'm newish to c# and i was wondering if someone would be kind enoth to explain or point me to the right place to search tho a gsc file that is formatted something like this

```
else if( GetDvar( "zombiemode" ) ) // CODER_MOD (Austin 5/4/08): zombiemode loadout setup
{
    add_weapon( "rich_b23r" );
    PrecacheItem( "napalmblob" );
    PrecacheItem( "napalmbloblight" );
    set_switch_weapon( "elf_galil" );

    set_laststand_pistol( "zombie_colt" );

    set_player_viewmodel( "origins_viewhands");
    set_player_interactive_hands( "origins_viewhands");

    level.campaign = "american";
    return;
}
```

like and say I wanted to get `add_weapon("rich_b23r");`

and just display rich_b23r into a text box and depending what is put i the text box i add a save button so say it loads the rich_b23r into the text box so what ever i put into that text box and pushed a button that says save

it will save the value into the the file inside the quotes

I just don't know how to go around doing this or how to even think about it but required for my program really so was wondering if someone could give me example code or point me into the right place.

Answer (score 0):

C# has a Replace method you can call on a string for example

This gives you "rich_b23r"

```
string someString = "\"rich_b23r\"";
```

This gives you rich_b23r

```
someString.Replace('"', '')
```

Then you can just assign it to the text box

```
textBox1.Text = someString.Replace('"','')
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: should have mentioned that its in a file and i have to find that part in the file and exucure it like that